# Convert hundreds of csv files into hdf5 files

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, hdf5

I found a lot of answers for this question but not for what I want to do specifically.
I have a a lot of csv files, some a few lines somme more than 200mo, for a total of ~70Go of data, and I'd like to convert them into hdf5 files.

I found ways that create a big dataframe and concatenate them all together, but my data is too large to fit in a single dataframe, using the solution shown here.
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/53125/file-converter-from-csv-to-hdf5

I'm trying to do something like 1 dataframe per file and convert them all into hdf5 files so that I have the same amount of h5 files and csv but I don't know that it's the right solution, as I don't think my computer can keep all of this in memory.

Something like that I found on another SO thread to put all the csv in one dataframe before converting:

```
from os import listdir

filepaths = [f for f in listdir("./data") if f.endswith('.csv')]
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, filepaths))
```

doesn't work because too many files/too heavy.

If you know of another solution please help,

Thanks

EDIT :

Thanks for the answers, it seems to work with this code:

```
for f in tqdm (listdir("E:\\Data\\Trades\\history")):
    if f.endswith('.csv'):
        pd.read_csv(f, 'rb').to_hdf('E:\\Data\\Trades\\hdf5_test.h5', key=f)
```

But I get this error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'trade_20141123.csv'`
That's the name of the first file in the list.

I also get this warning in jupyter :

```
ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex); you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.
  pd.read_csv(f, 'rb').to_hdf('E:\\Data\\Trades\\hdf5_test.h5', key=f)
C:\Users\Sam\anaconda3\envs\vaex_env\lib\site-packages\tables\path.py:155: NaturalNameWarning: object name is not a valid Python identifier: 'trade_20141122.csv'; it does not match the pattern ``^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$``; you will not be able to use natural naming to access this object; using ``getattr()`` will still work, though
  check_attribute_name(name)
```

Do I have to rename all the files ? I'm not sure that's the issue, but if it is what character is the problem ?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use list comprehension. just use a loop that reads, converts, and writes each file so you will not get too many files or run out of memory.

Edit 1: Do something like:

```
for f in listdir("./data"):
    if f.endswith('.csv'):
        pd.read_csv(f).to_hdf(...)
```

Take a look at this [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/49zi9s/quickly_converting_many_csv_files_to_a_single/).

Edit 2: try something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os, shutil, time, h5py

root_dir = './data/'  # Unique results directory
filepath = os.path.join(root_dir, 'file{0:03d}.csv')
hdfpath = os.path.join(root_dir, 'results.h5')

n_files = 10
n_rows = 100
n_cols = 10

if True:
    # Clear previous results
    if os.path.isdir(root_dir):
        shutil.rmtree(root_dir)
        os.makedirs(root_dir)
    for i in range(n_files):
        print("write csv file:",i)
        results = np.random.random((n_rows, n_cols))
        np.savetxt(filepath.format(i), results, delimiter=',')

# Convert the many csv files into a single hdf file
start_time = time.time()

for f in os.listdir("./data"):
    if f.endswith('.csv'):
       x='./data/'+f
       y='./data/'+f+'.hd5'
       df=pd.read_csv(x, 'rb',engine='python')
       df.to_hdf(y, key=f)

print('%s seconds' % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: I don't know how to convert to hdf5 without pandas, is that what you meant ?

Comment: no, just make an explicit loop: \pd.read_csv('input_file.csv').to_hdf('output_file.hdf5', key='data')"

Comment: THank you very much for the help, if you have time I edited the question to add a new issue I encounter, but if you don't know you already did a lot cheers !

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it didn't really work for me but I think it's close to what I need, I'll take a break from python and come back at this in a week or so and I will hopefully post what worked for me. Thanks a lot for your time and help, I really appreciate it

Comment: how does it fail?

Comment: it wiped out everything in the folder and replaced it with other csv files, I know I did something wrong but at that point I was kind of burned out of this problem and python learning so I'll take a week of and get back to it haha, thanks again sir !

Comment: my apologies, i should have used a different name for the data directory. change the code to use 'tempdata' or something other  than 'data'. also, you might consider making the .csv files read only.